# 3D Geometry missing in Revit File after model derivative SVF translation

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I'm trying to translate Revit file that contains both 3D and 2D geometries. I've verified that the file contains proper 3D geometry, by opening it in revit 2019 and visualizing it through 3D viewing mode.

However, when I pass this file into model derivative process, it only creates 2D derivative.

Before translation process, I've tried to set default view of the revit file as '3D' instead of 2D drawing file, which didn't work.
I've also tried making a translation POST request with formats as 'svf', and views as both ('3D', '2D'), and ('3D' only), which both failed.

However, all these attempts didn't work, and when I inspected the manifest from the file translation, it seems like that 3D geometry is completely missing. I think that there is a unhandled exception in Model Derivative process that fails to extract 3D geometry in our particular forge model file.

If you need URN of the file / actual file, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

---

### - EDIT

UPDATE:
I've confirmed that the default 3D view is named as {3D}, default name set by Revit.

Answer (score 0):

What is the name of your default 3D view?

The default name is "{3D}", I believe.

Maybe the translation process does not pick it up if it is named differently.

Afaik, the one and only way to specify the views for the translator to process is by using the [Collaboration for Revit or C4R](http://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2017/ENU/?guid=GUID-95DA7950-294A-442F-B82A-218E45D79C66) BIM 360 Team tool to [select the views to publish to the cloud](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2017/09/revit-20181-nuget-packages-rooms-and-views-in-forge.html#2).

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the confusion. I've confirmed that the default 3D view is named as {3D}, default name set by Revit.